# Bazel Question: `filegroup` to `declare_directory`

Tags: bazel, bazel-rules, starlark

I have a general question about how to make `filegroup` into a `declare_directory`.

So what I can think about is like,
`filegroup` -> `pkg_tar` -> `untar_to_dir`(A rule to untar the tarball into the `declare_directory`).

It would work, and I already proved it. However, I want to know whether any other more graceful method to avoid tar and untar the filegroup?

One idea I tried, but much complicated, is to copy them into the `declare_directory` file by file. But the tricky point is, it could not gracefully deal with keeping the same dir structure in the new dir. (like I have to `mkdir` a lot of sub-directory before `cp`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From another thread

```
You can just use `cp` instead of `tar`, like this rule does https://github.com/aspect-build/bazel-lib/blob/main/docs/copy_to_directory.md
it takes sources which can include filegroup, and outputs a TreeArtifact (ctx.actions_declare_directory)
```

And actually I wrote a func files_to_dir and did the same thing.